# ConfigurationManager Class not exist on .NET 4.5 Framework

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5

I just start working with .NET Framework 4.5 of C#. Am using Windows Form Application. I have do the needed imports such as :

```
using System.Configuration;
```

But actually the ConfigurationManager class seems that it is not exits. I have tried to use ConfigurationSettings instead , but Visual Stdio telling me that it is obsolete and replaced by ConfigurationManager !

This is chunk of code related to the problem :

```
Int32.Parse StartingMonth = int.parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StartingMonthColumn"]);
```

So , could you please help me ?

Comment: Do you have reference added to System.Configuration assembly?

Comment: Reference is added and this also not solved the problem !

Answer (score 59):

1. Make sure that you add `System.Configuration.dll` to the project. If you already added it, try to remove and add it again.
2. Put the cursor on `ConfigurationManager` then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>, and see what it suggests you.

Comment: on #1 - under your project, right click on references, click add reference, and the System.Configuration.dll should be available on the first tab ".NET"

Answer (score 25):

RightClick on project -> Add-> Reference...-> Assemblies-> Framework 
Select the System.Configuration (checked)
Should solve the problem.

Comment: This worked for me

Answer (score 5):

ConfigurationManager is present in System.Configuration namespace but it need System.Configuration assembly in your project.

Answer (score 3):

It is because of reference , I just restarted the project after adding the reference and it is working OK :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to find the reference here is the correct path

"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a"

Go to the Add reference and select the browser option and go to the above link. Then you can add the System.Configuration.dll