# ConfigurationManager is not available

Tags: c#, using, configurationmanager

I am trying to add the `ConfigurationMangager` in my programm. I've already tried to add the `System.Configuration` and `System.Configuration.Install` reference but nothing works. Is there any other way I could fix this problem?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace Gmos.Halbtax.Models
{
    static class Program
    {
        public static void connectDB()
        {
            string connString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnString"].ToString();
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);          
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: define: "nothing works"? (An error, not the behaviour you expect -we're not mind readers) and why are you using an app setting instead of the `connectionStrings` element for storing a connection string?

Comment: the ConfigurationManager gets underlined in a red color --> its not getting recognized @Jamiec

Comment: Then you're missing a reference to `System.Configuration` (not a `using` - the actual reference)

Comment: You may be missing a reference. add a reference to `System.Configuration` to your project and then rebuilding.

Comment: Have you tried recompiling the solution after adding the references? Also, just in case, have you tried simply restarting VS (helps sometimes in such cases)?

Comment: Possible solution here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12947179/configurationmanager-class-not-exist-on-net-4-5-framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make Sure Target framework is `NET framework 4` and the version you select for `System.Configuration` is `v4.0.0.0`

Add `System.Configuration` in your project by clicking add Reference on your project

> To check go to your Project Properties -> Application -> Target framework

Hope this will hep you.

Comment: unfortunately this is not my problem -.- but thanks for your answer @Ansari

Comment: @AlessandroMinneci if you need to get value from app setting then this you can try `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnString"]` else if you want connection string from web config you can use `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString` all you need to add `System.Configuration.dll` to your project

Answer (score 0):

If the reference doesn`t show up: do you use the *client profile* version of *.Net Framework 4*? If so download the whole framework and it should be fixed.
If you already use the full version try running a repair... in some rare cases this behaviour happens